# Change ion-nav-button when form gets valid

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is there a way to disable/enable a ion-nav-button when a form is validated?

As I see, they do not see each other, because i tryed **ng-show="myForm.$valid"** and it didn´t work.

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
    <button ng-show="myForm.$valid"  class="button button-dark" ng-click="add()">Save</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

I´ve tryed to get the form in controller side to set ng-show with a boolean variable, but I can´t get it too.

Any help or sugestions?

[An CodePen example](http://codepen.io/frcol/pen/zqQXpe)

Comment: Post your code with question

Comment: @Fabio Colombini: your button is inside of form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Final Edit:**

To reference the form from outside, give it a name at the root scope level:

```
<button ng-show="$root.myForm.$valid">Save</button>

<form name="$root.myForm"> 
</form>
```

this will show the button only when the whole form is valid.

Comment: When I put the example from your link inside ionic, it does not work anymore. I put an example above.

Comment: why did you hardcode the form name? you need to pass it in the function `ng-show="anyDirtyAndInvalid(myForm)"`

Comment: Even doing that does not work. And from your link there is this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/j1xT4NUBhPZCgkyd0dBl?p=info) that does not send the form as parameter.

Comment: For the <span> it worked, but still not working for the ion-nav-button.

Comment: See my edit, I tested on your codepen and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
    <button ng-hide="myForm.$invalid"  class="button button-dark" ng-click="add()">Save</button>
</ion-nav-buttons>


<form name="myForm">
    <input name="userName" type="text" ng-model="userName" required />    
</form>
```

Comment: No, it didn´t work. I have already tryied it, but tried again.

Comment: please create a cod pen

Comment: i can´t get it working with ionic in codepen or plunker. But i put an example above.